# KeywordQuery Searching by URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, keywordquery

I am still new  in [SharePoint](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) so I would like to ask you about the `keywordQuery`.
I need to send and URL with item ID like an `QueryText` because I do not know how to get the file with URL.

For example:

```
...Lists/Temp%List/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

So the URL should be in the `QueryText`.

*Is it possible to allow search in SharePoint with URL?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from search, URL or a REST query.

Search: path:"http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/yourListLibrary" ListItemId=2

URL: http://yourServer/sites/search/pages/results.aspx?k=path%3A%22http%3A%2F%2FyourServer%2Fsites%2FyourSite%2FyourListLibrary%22%20ListItemId%3D2

REST: http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/search/query?querytext='path:"http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/yourListLibrary" ListItemId=2'